# discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: extension is a required argument that is missing

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am new to cogs and was trying to setup a cog ...watching from a tutorial and understanding a bit everything seems to be ok ...as i added a command **.load** and when i try to load the cog it shows an missing argument error..

```
import os
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot Is Ready!')

@client.command()
async def load(ctx, extension):
    client.load_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')

@client.command()
async def unload(ctx, extension):
    client.unload_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')

for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
        client.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
```

Cog Moderation.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class Moderation(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client



def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Moderation(client))
```

error

```
Ignoring exception in command load:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nucleo\Desktop\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Nucleo\Desktop\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 851, in invoke
    await self.prepare(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Nucleo\Desktop\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 786, in prepare
    await self._parse_arguments(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Nucleo\Desktop\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 706, in _parse_arguments
    kwargs[name] = await self.transform(ctx, param)
  File "C:\Users\Nucleo\Desktop\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 542, in transform
    raise MissingRequiredArgument(param)
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: extension is a required argument that is missing.
```

Comment: How do you execute your commands?

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake when i used just **.load** instead of **.load [cog]** ^^! .Thanks For The Help Still!